# Array created from file, program hangs on any method using it

Tags: java

[DISCLAIMER] I'm not really sure how to word this question well, but I will try my best. I also attempted to search, but don't quite know the best keywords so please do forgive me if the question has already been answered.

I am creating a program for a class that produces statistics from temperatures stored in a file. The temps are stored in centigrade, and converted to fahrenheit by the program.

The driver file is used to find mins and maxes, etc.

The problem I'm currently running into, is whenever I attempt to instantiate, and then use the array in any of my created methods the program hangs, and will not display anything further. The program does not terminate, rather it just hangs.

My suspicion is that it may have something to do with one of my loops, but I've been looking over this project for the past three days, to no success.

Thank you for your time!

Both files are listed below.

```
package tempStats;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.*;



public class TempDriver {
    public static void main(String args[]) {

    //VARIABLES
        double[] data = new double[12];
        String filepath = "f:\\temp.dat";   

    //CALLS
    data = readFile(filepath);  

    //OUTPUT
    System.out.println("   Temperature Statistics in Centigrade");
    System.out.println("  --------------------------------------");

    Temp temp = new Temp(data);

     //System.out.println(temp.toString());
     //System.out.println("Temparature Statistics in Fahrenheit : ");
    // System.out.println("*************************************** ");


     for(double d : data)
         System.out.println(d);
}


//Reads file data into array
public static double[] readFile(String filepath) {
    Scanner inFile = null;
    double[] data = new double[12];
    try {
        inFile = new Scanner(new File(filepath));
    }
    catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        System.out.println("File not found.");
        System.exit(-1);
    }

        for(int i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
            data[i] = inFile.nextDouble();
        }
        inFile.close();


    return data;
  }
}
```

xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx

```
import java.text.DecimalFormat;

public class Temp {
//INSTANCE VARIABLES
private double arr[];
private double avg = 0;
private int maxIndex = 0;
private int minIndex = 0;

//DECLARES MONTH ARRAY
private String [] months = {"January", "February", "March", "April", "May", 
"June", "July",
        "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"};


//CONSTRUCTOR
public Temp(double[] arr) {
    this.arr = arr;
    this.avg = 0;
    this.maxIndex = 0;
    this.minIndex = 0;

//      for(int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
//          System.out.println(arr[i]);
//      }
    }

//CALCULATES AVERAGE OF CENTAGRADE VALUES
public double calcAvg() {
    double tempAvg= 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++ ) {
        tempAvg += arr[i];
    }
    this.avg = tempAvg / 12;
    System.out.println(tempAvg);
    return avg;
}

//FINDS MAXIMUM VALUE AND INDEX
public double findMax() {
    double maxValue = arr[0];
    for(int i = 1;  i < arr.length;) {
        if(arr[i] > maxIndex) {
            maxValue = arr[i];
            maxIndex = i;
        }
    }
    this.maxIndex = maxIndex;
    System.out.println(maxValue);
    return maxValue;
}

//FINDS MINIMUM VALUE AND INDEX
public double findMin() {
    double minValue = arr[0];
    for(int x = 1; x < arr.length;) {
        if(arr[x] < minIndex) {
            minValue = arr[x];
            minIndex = x;
        }
    }
    this.minIndex = minIndex;
    System.out.println(minValue);
    return minValue;
}

//CONVERTS CENTAGRADE VALUES TO FAHRENHEIT
public void convertToFah(double[]arr) {
    for(int i = 0; i < arr.length;) {
        arr[i] = ((arr[i] * 9) / 5.0) + 32;
    }
}

//CONVERTS ARRAY TO STRING FOR DISPLAY
public String toString() {
    DecimalFormat dec = new DecimalFormat("0.##");
    double maximum = findMax();
    double minimum = findMin();
    return "Average Temperature:\t" + dec.format(calcAvg()) + 
            "\n High Temperature:\t" + months[maxIndex] + "  " + 
dec.format(maximum) + 
            "\n Low Temperature:\t" + months[minIndex] + "  " + 
dec.format(minimum) + 
            "\n ";
   }
}
```

Comment: You have a number of infinite loops: `for(int i = 1;  i < arr.length;)`

Comment: Now I feel silly for not realizing such an obvious mistake, but thank you for such a fast response, and for your help. Due date is in a couple hours and you just saved me!

Comment: For future reference, if you are stuck with a program that doesn't terminate you can run it with a debugger and step through it, so you can see how far it gets. If you don't have a debugger available, put in System.out.println(...) statements at various points to tell you which lines it gets to.